# Tasks on my Project do not print

Tags: ms-project

I am using MS Project at work, and I noticed on one job when I print the calendar, certain tasks do not show up. It appears that every task that is lower in the day cell does not show up on the Print.

See picture. On the left is the print, on the right is the calendar view of the project.

[image: print and calendar view]

I do not understand why some tasks are toward the bottom of the day cell, and others are at the top.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You can move tasks in the Calendar view around and my guess is, that is how the bars are now appearing in the lower part of the day.  Right click in the background of the Calendar view, select **Layout Now** to apply an auto layout to the view.  However, if you have more than 4 to 5 tasks on any day, they will not all print - they will show on an "Overflow page" in the print out.  If you have multiple overlapping tasks, consider filtering the view to remove tasks that are not of interest - for example, filter the view for a specific resource or resource group.

Comment: great you helped me find it. So in Gantt view I had sorted by ID. When i switched to Gregorian Calendar The tasks stay in that sort. So when i right click on a day and choose layout, method shows  "Use current sort order" and ID (ascending) is listed. When i choose "Attempt to fit as many tasks as possible" all the tasks arrange at the top of the day. and they print.

Comment: Great.  I' glad you found the method to make it work.